# What variable does discord.py assign when user : user.mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i'm trying to make a spam bot (the server using it requested.)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def mention(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    while(1+1==2):
        if user == ("@irlydontknow"):
            print("No")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}')
client.run('no')
```

but i would like to have a blacklist option so it would never ping the listed people. Thats where  `if user ==("@irlydontknow"): print("no")`
comes in, instead of pinging it just says no. How would I make this do this, currently it doesn't work. and yes I know that while(1+1==2) is a sloppy way of looping

Answer (score 0):

You could user the ID of the user you want to not be mentioned. For Example:

```
if user.id == int(your_id):
  print("no")
```

**You can make this into a list of users by using `if user.id in [user1ID, user2ID]`**

To get your ID you can implement a simple function that prints your `user.id`

Comment: how would i add 2 of them?, i dont know how to use your list method, but the 1st method does work for 1 person

Comment: @JonathanKim If this answer helped you don't forget to mark it so that others know that this works!